# How to convert currency to Paypal accepted currency on checkout

Tags: wordpress, paypal

I am trying to change programmatically the currency from KES to USD when checking out with "Paypal Express Checkout" plugin.
This should happen when someone clicks on the Paypal checkout button.
If anyone has the knowledge on how to do this kindly assist.

Comment: Anyone, besides the dude with the uppercase comment?

Comment: Please Checkout this answer it might help: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/303628/how-to-change-currency-programmatically-on-creating-order-action

Comment: Thank you @Abhisheksingh . But I tried it before posing the question did not work.

Comment: I solved it myself, I finally had to go into the Paypal code and change it manually.